# Transform from DenseAxisArray to Array

Tags: arrays, julia, julia-jump

is there an easy way to transform a DenseAxisArray to a "normal" array/matrix?
What I have been doing until now is,

```
  if typeof(a[i]) <: JuMP.Containers.DenseAxisArray
        a[i] = [a[i][1][j] for j in eachindex(a[i][1]) ]
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array(a[i])`.

See the documentation: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/manual/containers/#Access-internal-data